# Windows Phone Test Framework - NuGet - Testing a new App

Tags: windows-phone, nuget

I have followed your test app example from [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yYrkGNysGhU). I have also created the ACL for port 8085 using below command.  (with Mydomain and myusracc being my work domain and user account)

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:8085/ user=<mydomain>\<myusracc>
```

When I run the solution in debug mode, I'm getting below error:

> There was no endpoint listening at `http://localhost:8085/phoneAutomation/automate` that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.

I tried executing the SpecFlow scenarios, I get below exception:

```
App not alive - ping failed
  Expected: True
  But was:  False
```

I ran the command to see which ports are lisening, (netstat -an |find /i "listening") and couldn't find 8085

If I ran the netsh command again to create the ACL, I get a message saying URL is already there and is listed as follows:

```
Reserved URL            : http://+:8085/
   User: <mydomain>\<myusername>
       Listen: Yes
       Delegate: No
       SDDL: D:(A;;GX;;;S-1-5-21-xxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx)
```

Answer (score 3):

I has the same questions and what I have found about second question: [manual](https://github.com/Expensify/WindowsPhoneTestFramework/wiki/Installing-from-NuGet) at GitHub isn't correct in example part and I use their examples from source code - they work fine.

Try to change your SpecFlow feature to something like:

```
Feature: MainPage
    In order to test my app
    As a WP7 Developer
    I want to see it start and take a picture of it

Scenario: Main Page loads after a few seconds
    Given my app is clean installed and running
    Then take a picture
```